# Is there a web app that gives single book recommendations?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've been searching for a website that basically does something very similar to the following flow chart ([link](http://www.box.net/shared/static/a6omcl2la0ivlxsn3o8m.jpg) if it's too small to see):

[image: Flow Chart of Awesomeness]

I'm basically looking for a site that asks simple questions like the flowchart does and gives a single book recommendation.

I found `www.whatshouldireadnext.com` but that basically gives a list of recommendations based on Amazon's "Customers who bought this also bought..." database (I'm assuming).

Does anyone know of anything like this? Am I SOL?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know something that would do something similar to this flow but you can try [TasteKid](http://www.tastekid.com) and [GoodReads](http://www.goodreads.com).
In Goodreads you should rate some books to have recommendations. In Tastekid you just need to write the book's or author's name.

Comment: I've used GoodReads and I just tried out TasteKid and they both seem to do what whatshouldireadnext.com does. TasteKid seems to be exactly like that except with movies music and TV added.

Answer (score 0):

[Hunch](http://hunch.com/)  does what you're asking for - asks for some questions about what you like and provides recommendations.

Another webapp which provides recommendations based on what you've read is [GetGlue](http://getglue.com/)